# Nodejs how to combine two Unicode code into a Unicode code, for example, "\ud859\udfcc" into "\u000267cc"

Tags: node.js, unicode

Nodejs how to combine two Unicode code into a Unicode code, for example, `\ud859\udfcc` into `\u000267cc`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Please  open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).